# How to create an inverted triangle using only loops/control statements and two cout statements: one that outputs '#' and one that outputs '\n'

Tags: c++, algorithm, character

The output is supposed to look as follows:

```
########
 ######
  ####
   ##
```

I have solved the issue by dropping the only two cout statements constraint:

```
#include <iostream>

void main(){
int startHash = 8;
for(int row = 1; row <= 4; row++){
    for(int hashNum = 1; hashNum <= startHash; hashNum++){
        std::cout << "#";
    }
    std::cout << "\n ";
    if(row == 2) std::cout << " ";
    if(row == 3) std:: cout << "  ";
    if(row == 4) std:: cout << "   ";
    startHash -= 2;
}
system("PAUSE");
}
```

However, at this point I can't figure out how to make this shape without being able to output a space, since cout always starts at the far left and moves to the right. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're not allowed to use spaces to space out your output, then you must use `setw` from the `iomanip` header.

Comment: I think it is more likely that he is under artificial constraint of only two statements containing `std::cout`, or only two calls of `<<` operator on `std::cout` rather than not being able to print a space, and seeing how he "used them up" for printing hashes and newline...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how your the spaces in your ifs are slowly getting longer:

```
if(row == 2) std::cout << " ";
if(row == 3) std:: cout << "  ";
if(row == 4) std:: cout << "   ";
```

It seems that there is pattern there, see if you can find it. ;-)

(Seeing how this has roughly 100% chance of being homework question, work for it.)

Comment: It's not a homework question, but it is an exercise from a book I'm working through on my own. 

I see that the spaces are incrementing by one. Using setw with an incrementing counter as ooga suggested is completely doable; however, were you thinking of a better solution?

Comment: There are 2 more solutions that are reasonably easy to implement and should be at your current skill level. One is to first marshal the formatted output in a temporary buffer (say... `std::stringstream`) and then just throw it to `std::cout`, which will let you basically print everything by using `std::cout` once. The one I was hinting at was to just use for loop for printing spaces, at which point you will need one statement with `cout` for spaces, one for `#` and you will have to figure out how literal you want to be with the restrictions. (There are many fun ways to technically have only 2

Comment: ... statements with `cout` but have branching, newlines, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

There are other output devices other than `std::cout`

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
int startHash = 8;
for(int row = 1; row <= 4; row++){
    for(int hashNum = 1; hashNum <= startHash; hashNum++){
        std::cout << "#";
    }
    std::cout << "\n ";
    if(row == 2) std::clog << " ";
    if(row == 3) std::clog << "  ";
    if(row == 4) std::clog << "   ";
    startHash -= 2;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even though it could use improvement, I don't think the question is bad enough to deserve being trolled.

Comment: @Xarn I'm not trolling, only pointing out another solution to the prompt

Comment: @Xarn What was bad about this question? I'm new to the site and this was my first post, so any constructive criticism is welcome.

Comment: @Kris I think the question was fine, it just sounded like HW

Comment: @awesomeyi Ah, gotcha. It's an exercise from a book I'm working through in my spare time, so I can definitely see where you guys are coming from.

Comment: @Kris Basically, homework questions are frowned upon for various reasons + The question sounds as if a paragraph went missing during submit. It starts with expected output, then you say that you've dropped some restriction, but at no point you have stated what the actual problem/question was. Luckily, this is basically standard homework for programming 101, learning about loops. Otherwise, the question was rather decent. It was written in reasonably good english, contained minimal reproducible test case, etc.

Comment: @Xarn Got it. I thought the title would work as a problem statement, but in the future I'll type out the full problem statement in the body. Thanks for the input!